# Difference between "extreme peril", "mortal danger" and "grave danger"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I have encountered a phrase, that sounds quite natural to me:

> puts their lives in **grave danger**

But I have also found two more phrases that should share a similar meaning:

- extreme peril;
- mortal danger.

What are the difference between those three?

Comment: The connotation with "mortal danger" and "grave danger", which can be intuited given the meanings of the modifying nouns, is that there's a chance the person in question could actually die. Extreme peril is less severe to my eye.

Comment: @JohnClifford *Grave* doesn't refer to death in this context.

Comment: @Era guess that's just my love of double meanings tripping up my intepretation. :)

Answer (score 2):

*Extreme peril* and *grave danger* mean about the same thing. *Peril* and *danger* are synonyms. *Grave* here means "severe or serious": it's related to the word *gravity* which is used figuratively to talk about the "weight" of a situation.

*Mortal danger* specifically means that the person's life is at stake. Here *mortal* refers to death.